# Asp .net web api 2 doesn't return true http error in case of an exception with autofac

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, autofac

Global exception handler handles the exceptions thrown from the controllers by creating an HttpResponseMessage. This apparently leads to a true http error.

After integrating with Autofac, exception is not seen as a failure. The client sees it as a successful response.

Is it something to do with the autofac configuration?

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi - {5.2.0}
Autofac - {3.5.2}
Autofac.WebApi2 - {4.0.0}
```

Autofac configuration:

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var modules = new List<Module>() { new AutofacModule() };
        modules.ForEach(m => builder.RegisterModule(m));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(builder.Build());
```

AutofacModule:

```
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
    }
```

Comment: Nothing appears wrong on the surface, but it would probably be good to post a repro with more details. What exactly was working before? What does the controller look like? You're registering the Autofac filter provider, what filters have you added? Do you see other errors? What are they exactly, with stack traces? If you literally just remove these Autofac lines (and only these lines) is it fixed? Much, much more detail is required here.

Comment: The issue was with the client which had a buggy custom http interceptor. It has got nothing to do with the web api or autofac. Thanks for the reply, Travis.